# Problem with Postgres: "pg_ctl: could not start server"

Tags: postgresql

When I execute command:

> pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l
> /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start

I get this error:

```
pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
waiting for server to start.... stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output
```

My postgres started:

> brew services start postgresql

Comment: So what's in the server log?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should proceed like this:

1. Look at `/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`.
   In the first line, you will find a process ID.
2. Look if there is a process running with the process ID found in the first step.

   - If yes, check if it is a PostgreSQL process.

     - If yes, then your server is already running.
     - if not, remove `postmaster.pid` (but **never, ever** remove that file if the process ID belongs to a PostgreSQL process). Then start PostgreSQL like indicated in the next step.
   - If not, start PostgreSQL again like you did, but add `-t 1000` to `pg_ctl`, so that it waits 1000 seconds for PostgreSQL to start up.

Answer (score 2):

In windows, look for postgres processes running in background.

To kill with command line, taskkill /f /IM postgres*

Comment: I don't think the questioner was asking about a Windows system.

Answer (score 0):

I am faced like this problem, when i ran CMD as administrator, the command  worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly highlights that there is already a postgreSQL server. So, first kill the existing server to free up that port using

**Note: Change port number if your server is running on a port different than the default one**

```
lsof -i tcp:5432
```

This will return any existing processes running on that port and return their **PID**. Copy the PID and run the following to kill the process.

```
sudo kill PID
```

- Replace **PID** with your process's PID.

Answer (score 0):

I had a different problem - so documenting it in case it helps someone. **Another process** (Chrome) **had the same PID** which was previously assigned to Posgres.

While following @Laurenz Albe's answer (which helped me figure this out), this is what happened:

1. I ran
   `cat /Users/<my-user>/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-9.6/postmaster.pid` (that's where the file was on my Mac)
2. First line gave a process ID. I searched for it:
   `ps -ef | grep <id-from-first-line-above>`
3. Chrome was running on that ID :)
4. I quit Chrome (manually)
5. Postgres started up fine (I am using the Postgres app)